# LAN simulation using Java?

Tags: java, simulation, lan

I have to create a Java program that simulates around 50-100 nodes. I want to test a few routing algorithms and analyse network performance. I tried simulating nodes with threads, but my CPU utilization goes up like anything when I use more threads. Is there a method to simulate a network in Java. If so what way?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to pursue *why* it "goes up like anything", since Java can handle lots of threads?

Comment: Unless you have thousands of connections, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Without some code nobody can really tell you why your CPU utilization goes high.   If you use threads correctly, they'll spend most of their time waiting for "events" (timer or data flow) and consume very little CPU.  Maybe you have a busy-wait loop?

Comment: Yes, garrison.I used a busy wait loop(Im a learner still).But how do i wake a thread based on events?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a proxy server which passes traffic after a delay which can include a delay based on a bandwidth limitation.  This is not as good as a real LAN in showing all the problems you can have, but it can be a good start.